# select specific columns on nested lists

Tags: lambda, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

im using EF 5 and lambda i need to know how to load specifict columns from diferent database tables,

lests say i jave a table A, and i need some columns of this table(lest say 10 from 30), also there is a B and C table, A contains many B, and B contains a C, and i need some of the a columns some of the b and some of the c, dont want to get all of them because there are to many columns that i wont use on some functions.

for when i need them i have somthing like

```
return context.A.include("B.C").toList();
```

but how can i filter specific columns for A, B and C?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Projection into a new anonymous type. Are you saying that there is a one to many between A and B.. and there is a one to many between B and C?

Comment: yes, actually b is the union betwen a and c, but i like to know how for generic situations

Comment: Are you saying that B contains ALL the records from A and ALL the records from C?

Comment: no sorry i use a bad word (union), B is the result of a n to n betwen A and C + some more data, but taths not the point i need to lnow how to get specific columns of table and (if any) inlcude other child entities

Comment: I don't think there exists a generic way for all the cases. However with somehow messy lines of code what you want is possible and I already tried it. Let me know if you are interested.